# Trapezoid - prove that distance between diagonals and segments parallel to diagonals are the same

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, area

I want to prove that $H$ lie on $EF$ where $H$ is intersect of $KJ$ and $LI$.
$E$ and $F$ are midpoints of $AB$ and $CD$.
$A_{KBJ}=A_{AKJCD}=A_{ALI}=A_{LBCDI}$ where $A$ is Area.
$KJ$ is paralell to $AC$ and $LI$ is paralell to $BD$.
I would be able to prove that $H$ lie on $EF$ if I know for sure that $ND=AK$.
So my question is how to prove that $ND=AK$?

Triangle sketch:
[image: Triangle sketch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=CD$, $b=AB$ be the bases, $h$ the height of the trapezoid (see diagram below), and set $AK=x$. To have $A_{ABCD}=2A_{BJK}$ we need then
$$
(a+b)h=2(b-x)(h-y).
$$
From the similitude of triangles $ABC$ and $PJC$ one gets $y=(h/b)x$: plugging this into the above equation yields
$$
b(a+b)=2(b-x)^2,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
AK=x=b-\sqrt{b(a+b)\over2}.
$$
Notice that this result does not depend on which diagonal $KJ$ is parallel to: we can then repeat the same argument for $BL$ and obtain the same result. Hence $AK=BL$.

[image]